# iOS : Keep socket persistent after background

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, background, keep-alive

With iOS 7, suspended background is now enable after 3 minutes. After this 3 minutes, all sockets are deleted by the system. I know that it is possible to tag a socket as VoIP socket to keep this socket active in background but :

1. Is there any others solutions ?
2. If i have 2 sockets, is it possible to tag these 2 sockets as VoIP sockets ?

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Is you application a VOIP application? If not, tagging it as such will get it rejected. If it is, then it is the solution you need.

Comment: Yes, it is a Voip application, but i don't know how many socket i can tag as VoIP sockets ? In my app, i would like to tag 2 sockets

Answer (score 1):

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) implicitly mentions that only one socket will be managed by the operating system.

> Configure one of the app’s sockets for VoIP usage.

It is possible to mark multiple sockets as VoIP sockets, but only one of these sockets will be managed by the operating system when your application is pushed to the background. The documentation doesn't specify the behavior of multiple VoIP sockets and my recommendation is therefore to only mark one socket as a VoIP socket.